# Reload Page After Delete in PHP

Tags: php

I have made this function to delete the record from the table. When the delete operation is done, the page displays all data(including the deleted one), But, I need to refresh or reload the page to see the results after I have deleted the row. How it can be done in following code? Thanx in advance!!

```
            public function deletedata(){

        if(isset($_GET['del_id'])){

            $delete_id = $_GET['del_id'];

            $query ="DELETE FROM tbl_data WHERE project_id ='".$delete_id."' ";

            $this->databaseObject->getConnection()->query($query);
    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd use the `header` function to reload a page.

Something like this should work: `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Alternatively, depending on the structure of your code you could simply call the delete code before the code that retrieves the records. That way you'd avoid the need to reload the page.

Comment: I have done this :::
public function deletedata(){
 
  if(isset($_GET['del_id'])){
  
  $delete_id = $_GET['del_id'];
  
  $query ="DELETE FROM tbl_data WHERE project_id ='".$delete_id."' ";
  
  $this->databaseObject->getConnection()->query($query);
  
  header('Location: http://localhost/backend/class/datadisplayclass.php');
  
  }

But following error occured:::"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\class\datadisplayclass.php:62) in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\class\datadisplayclass.php on line ...
"

Comment: Yes you cannot use a header redirect if you have already outputted any content. This content could be text or simply a newline character. So just make sure your redirect occurs before any output.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in laurencek's alternative, there's probably no need to reload the page.
Just perform any necessary record deletion before rendering the HTML.

```
<?php

$delete_id=isset($_GET['del_id'])&&is_numeric($_GET['del_id'])?$_GET['del_id']:false;
if ($delete_id) {
  $query ="DELETE FROM tbl_data WHERE project_id ='".$delete_id."' ";
  $this->databaseObject->getConnection()->query($query);
}
$query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE 1;";
$this->databaseObject->getConnection()->query($query);

?>
<html>

// some php/html to loop through the query and display records

</html>
```

This assumes your IDs are numeric.
If not, I strongly suggest checking/escaping the variable before introducing it to your database.

Comment: just to clarify due to the "modify header" comment - Your page should start with a <?php tag, then have your delete function, then have your select data query (eg: you get your data AFTER you deleted stuff), then start <html> after that.

Comment: Agreed. My code is not a complete working example, just an example of the PHP required. I have added the PHP opening and closing tags in case that helps to clarify. Also, I'm suggesting that you DON'T need to modify the header or reload the page. Just perform the database alterations before rendering the HTML.